# In Cosmos DB, is there a max size of documents you can send to a Stored Procedure?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm getting a 'Request Size Too Large' Error in Cosmos.
I'm sending, eventually, the following documents (each row should create a document) to my Bulk Import Stored Procedure: 
[image: Document File Sizes Calculated 2 Ways]

None of these are over 2 MB unless I misunderstand 2MB to be somehow less than 1.5 million.

Size Calc:

```
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(series);
    var sizeMethod1 = json.Length * sizeof(Char);
    var sizeMethod2 = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json).Length;
    log.Info($"Document Size Method 1: {sizeMethod1} and Size Method 2: {sizeMethod2}");
```

It's very challenging to debug the stored procedure when it throws an error.

Comment: The 2MB limit makes SP a rather limited choice for bulk import. Maybe you should consider [Azure DocumentDB Data Migration Tool](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/documentdb-data-migration-tool/) instead?

Answer (score 1):

> It's very challenging to debug the stored procedure when it throws an
>   error.

You could use `console.log ()` to calculator the size of documents in your stored procedure as below.Then use [getScriptLog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.storedprocedureresponse-1.scriptlog?view=azure-dotnet) to get the output from stored procedure `console.log()` statements.

Please note that `EnableScriptLogging = true`  is necessary to print console.log:

```
var response = await client.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync(
    document.SelfLink,
    new RequestOptions { EnableScriptLogging = true } );
Console.WriteLine(response.ScriptLog);
```

You could refer to this [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.requestoptions.enablescriptlogging?view=azure-dotnet).

> I'm getting a 'Request Size Too Large' Error in Cosmos.

The request size is too large means you are sending too much input to the sproc. Max input size for script is currently 2MB. You could reduce your input documents to fit that restriction and follow the bulk insert sample on the official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/programming#example-bulk-importing-data-into-a-database-program).

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Strangely, I'm consistently sending requests to my stored procedure larger than 2mb...

Comment: @A.Rowan You mean you consistently sending requests and no error occurred before?

Comment: Yes.  The image above represents the bundle I'll send to the SP.  That one fails, but I consistently send ones that together are 2.8 or so.  Its kind of like the RU limit.  I consistently pull well over (10x to 100x) the limit and just get rate limited.